# How can I create an exception in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I try to solve folling problem with .htaccess.
I use it to rewrite everything to "https://" and put "www" in front of every url.
Now I want to use a SSL-certificate. To validate it, I put a html-file in a certain folder. I do not want this to be redirected to "www.". How can I create an exception only for this one file?
Thank you very much for helping me with this maybe kind of stupid question.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide an example of URL that should **not** be redirected to https. But here is an example. This is a simplified version of your .htaccess file.
I have combined the https and www redirect in one directive.
Assume your domain name is example.com.

There is a negative condition (note the exclamation mark). If the request URI does not begin with index.html then the rule fails and is not enforced.
So http://example.com/index.html will not be converted to https, but there is one important caveat: in this case the www. will not be added either. I understand this what you want, then we can have a simplified set or rules.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```